# How is this array different from dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, arrays

Let's say I write this snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int elements;
    printf("enter number of elements for array\n");
    scanf("%d", &elements);
    int arr[elements];
}
```

And I dynamically allocate memory for an array by `malloc`, whats the difference besides that `malloc` allocates memory in heap?. How much memory will be allocated in the first case at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main points:

1. `malloc` will usually align memory to `sizeof(max_align_t)` bytes while allocation on the stack won't.
2. Allocation on the stack can cause stack overflow while allocation with `malloc` should return an error upon memory overuse.
3. You are allowed to return a pointer returned by `malloc` but not a pointer from an allocation on the stack.

Comment: so can we say that this is allocating memory at run-time, although with potential errors?

Comment: @JerseyDevil Yes. It's unsafe unless you limit its size.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a **variable length array**.  They reside in the same place as other local variables, typically on the stack, and the space for them is set aside at runtime.

If you were to use `sizeof(arr)`, this would be one of the few instances where a `sizeof` expression is evaluated at runtime instead of compile time.

Comment: How? cl.exe gives me `error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant`` for the `int arr[elements];` line.

Comment: @Samuel You're probably compiling a C++ file.  Also, VS is not fully C compliant.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. It's asking the difference between this allocation and `malloc` (other than stack and heap), not what `arr` is.

Answer (score 0):

**Variable length arrays (VLA)** is a feature that is introduced by the C99 standard, and made optional by the C11 standard. The main difference between `malloc` allocations and **VLA** is that, returning the pointer obtained by calling `malloc` from a function is normal, but returning a local **VLA** (or more precisely, returning the pointer which points to the initial element of the array) from a function is almost always wrong. It is undefined behaviour if that pointer is used in the calling function. Compare these two functions:

```
int *f(int n)
{
    int arr[n]; // VLA
    /* Do some stuff */
    return arr; //  WRONG: returns address of local variable
}

int *g(int n)
{
    int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);
    if (arr == NULL) {
            /* Memory allocation failed. Treat accordingly */
    }

    /* Do some stuff */
    return arr;
}
```

Another difference is; there's no way to detect errors on large VLA allocations, but it is possible on `malloc` allocations by checking the pointer against `NULL`.